# Capybara can not find checkbox type label

Tags: xpath, checkbox, label, capybara, contains

I need to check checkbox type label input by text on label.

Actually I would want to check the checkbox by these values Mon, Tue, Wed there in html  tag, is it even possible?

The labels Mon Tue Wed ... are shown not like checkboxes, but look like buttons, basically i need to click on label or something...

My html looks like this:

```
    <div id="ck-button"><label><input tabindex="-1" id="checkbox_aghdfklg" 
    name="checkbox_fdhadfadf" type="checkbox"><span>Mon</span></label></div>

    <div id="ck-button"><label><input tabindex="-1" id="checkbox_0_aghdfklg" 
name="checkbox_0_fdhadfadf" type="checkbox"><span>Tue</span></label></div>

    <div id="ck-button"><label><input tabindex="-1" id="checkbox_1_aghdfklg" 
name="checkbox_1_fdhadfadf" type="checkbox"><span>Wed</span></label></div>
```

...
...

```
    <div id="ck-button"><label><input tabindex="-1" id="checkbox_5_aghdfklg" 
name="checkbox_7_fdhadfadf" type="checkbox"><span>Sun</span></label></div>
```

I would be satisfied enough if I could check checkbox_0_blabla but this blabla part changes every time I edit or change something on my webpage.

I have tried some ways already:

```
find(:xpath, '//*[contains(@id, "checkbox_1_")]').click()

find(:xpath, '//*[contains(@id, "checkbox_1_")]').set(true)
```

but I keep getting errors like:

> Unable to find xpath...

or

> invalid selector

and so on..

Maybe someone has some ideas?
Thank You!

Comment: Your path expression is correct. Sure that it is `.click()` and not `.click`?

Comment: It won't work with .click too... I don't know what to do. I also tried : `$campaign_weekdays = '//*[@id="ck-button"][3]/label'
$campaign_wednesday = '//*[contains(@id, "checkbox_1")]' `and  `within(:xpath, $campaign_weekdays)do
   find($campaign_wednesday ).click
 end` And it still says that invalid or illegal selector about campaign_wednesday

Comment: But if I select the wednesdays checkbox without using name or id tag, I would want to select it by this Wed text in html.. in this span tag...  I got it working  with this code : `find(:xpath, '//*[@id="ck-button"]/label/span[contains(., "Wed")]').click` thank you! I am so happy right now! :D